# CKAN install on reverse proxy logout failure

Tags: ckan

Our CKAN (2.7) server is installed on a Ubuntu 14.04 server, which is exposed to the Internet via port forwarding on the router.

We have trouble logging out of the server when CKAN is accessed from outside of the firewall with the following error msg:

```
http://192.168.0.35/user/logout?came_from=/user/logged_out_redirect is unreachable.
```

The error msg references the LAN address of the Ubuntu server instead of its WAN IP, could this be a configuration issue?

Thanks!

Bo

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your `ckan.site_url` setting. It should be your site's address, as seen by the outside world, rather than the internal name.

CKAN has a few links in it that are built from the ckan.site_url, and log-out is one of them, in recent CKAN versions.

Comment: Makes sense.  I updated the configuration ini file, that did not seem to work.  So I cleaned the database; but now it will not let me register user.  Here are  the error msgs in /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log

Comment: Here are the msgs: --- [Sun Oct 01 20:09:57.087960 2017] [:error] [pid 2598:tid 140410442872576] [remote 70.190.30.90:41439] mod_wsgi (pid=2598): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Sun Oct 01 20:09:57.088023 2017] [:error] [pid 2598:tid 140410442872576] [remote 70.190.30.90:41439] TypeError: expected byte string object for header name, value of type unicode found

Comment: You also need to restart apache2. Or did you do this?

Comment: CKAN doesn't know its running on IP 192.168.0.35 afaict, unless you told it in a .ini. Try searching for this in all your .ini files. Check you're editing the right .ini file - it's specified in wsgi.ini and is probably /etc/ckan/default/production.ini. You could try deleting the content temporarily and check apache gives an error. Regarding the TypeError, can you confirm the datestamp matches when you make the registration request exactly? It might be unrelated.

Comment: In my /etc/ckan/default folder, there are three files: apache.wsgi, production.ini, who.ini.  Only production.ini references to the site url. I now find my registration error may be related to other issues.  I will need to reinstall.  More later.